# Detect when PDA (Windows Mobile) is in flight mode

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile

I need to produce an error display message when the Windows Mobile PDA is in flight mode. The user will need to pull and push data from a SQL Server server; however when in flight mode this is not doable and a message needs to be displayed. Currently the message that is displayed is:

> a requeste to send information the the computer using IIS has failed.
>   For more results please see HRESULT

I am programming using VB.Net and I am fairly new to it. I have searched for the past week on the Internet and come across information suggesting that I use TAPI, however i do not know what to import, or where the "flight mode detection" code would go in my application.

Comment: Wouldn't you want something more generic, like simply handling when the device no longer is connected to a data-providing network?  "Flight Mode" is only one way to have the radio turned off, I'm sure the device can lose its Internet connectivity in a myriad of ways.

Comment: hi ckittel, this is how my manager has asked for it to be done so i thought id best do it that way. The program doesnt have to change the mode programmatically all it needs to do is display an alert message to inform user that flight mode is switched on

Answer (score 0):

Use the State and Notification Broker.  Use the [`SystemState class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.aspx) to read and/or monitor the value of something like [`SystemProperty.PhoneRadioOff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemproperty.aspx). [Here's an example of using the SNB](http://www.developer.com/ws/pc/article.php/3547381/Your-Windows-Mobile-50-Applications-Can-Monitor-Clients-and-Respond-to-Change.htm) (in C#, but simple enough to convert).